# How to create custom field in worpdress default widgets?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I want to create custom dropdown field with CSS animation settings, that would add different CSS classes to the Text Widget `<div>`.

I've done this for third-party widgets, but I can't imagine how to do this for default widgets, like `Text` or `Tag cloud`, because they're located in the `wp-includes` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit your theme functions.php file,

find : 
**register_sidebar** function

check out the **name** attribute in the function to make sure which widget you are going to update

There should be an attribute called **before_widget**

you can define your custom CSS Class name into it

here is the sample code for your reference

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'News Sidebar', 'left-test-sidebar' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'depnet' ),
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s YOUR-CUSTOM-CSS-CLASS">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title YOUR-CUSTOM-CSS-CLASS"><h4>',
    'after_title'   => '</h4></div>',
) );
```